# How can I resolve these errors in my code?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember, channel, message) => {
guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ew"));
    embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("User Join Notification")
        .setDescription("**guildMember.username** has joined this server.")
        .setColor("#21a1e1")
    message.channel.id('430681100956991511').sendEmbed(embed);
});
```

When I execute this code, when a user joins, it reports in the console *TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined*. How could I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `guildMemberAdd` event [only provides you with the `GuildMember` object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) so your `channel` and `message` variables are undefined.

Instead you want to get the channel to send the embed to through the `GuildMember` object:

```
guildMember.guild.channels.get("430681100956991511")
```

I believe